# Sudden change in picture quality in html canvas

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas

I am making a canvas project and using some .png pictures. I used it in one file, canvas drew it up perfectly and all was well. But when i tried to to the same thing in a different file the quality of the pictures sank for no apparent reason. Would love some help/explenation to why this occured!

Here are the difference in coding, just open the files to see the difference in quality.

"Good quality code"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Övning 1</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    *,body{
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        text-align: center;
        background:url('bilder/background.png');
    }
    canvas{
        border: 1px #999999 solid;
        margin-top: 50px;
        box-shadow: 2px 2px 1px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75) inset;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="900" height="400"></canvas>


    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
        var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

        var path = "bilder/helnot.png";
        var image1 = new DragImage(path, 200, 100);
        var image2 = new DragImage(path, 300, 100);

        var gKlav = new Image();
        gKlav.src = "bilder/g-klav.png";

        var loop = setInterval(function() {

        ctx.fillStyle = "#FFFFFF";
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 900, 400);

        image1.update();
        image2.update();
        }, 30);

        var mouseX = 0;
        var mouseY = 0;
        var mousePressed = false;
        var dragging = false;

        function DrawLines(){
            ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
            ctx.fillRect(50,160,800,1);
            ctx.fillRect(50,180,800,1);
            ctx.fillRect(50,200,800,1);
            ctx.fillRect(50,220,800,1);
            ctx.fillRect(50,240,800,1);
            ctx.drawImage(gKlav, 40, 40);
        }
        //Saves the cursers location into two vairables
        $(document).mousemove(function(e) {
        mouseX = e.offsetX;
        mouseY = e.offsetY;
        })

        //Specifies what happens when the mouse is clicked
        $(document).mousedown(function() {
            mousePressed = true;
        }).mouseup(function() {
            mousePressed = false;
            dragging = false;
        });

        //'this.x' and 'that.x' refers to the location of the top left corner of the image. 
        //'startX' and 'startY' refers to the distance between the curser and the image.
        function DragImage(src, x, y) {
            var that = this;
            var startX = 0;
            var startY = 0;
            var drag = false;

            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            var img = new Image();
            img.src = src;
            this.update = function() {
                if (mousePressed) {
                        var left = that.x;
                        var right = that.x + img.width;
                        var top = that.y;
                        var bottom = that.y + img.height;
                        if (!drag) {
                            startX = mouseX - that.x;
                            startY = mouseY - that.y;
                        }
                        if (mouseX < right && mouseX > left && mouseY < bottom && mouseY > top) {
                            if (!dragging){
                    dragging = true;
                                drag = true;
                            }

                        }

                } else {
                    drag = false;

                    $(document).mouseup(function(){
                        if((that.y + (img.height/2)) > 145 && (that.y + (img.height/2)) < 155){that.y = 140}
                        if((that.y + (img.height/2)) > 155 && (that.y + (img.height/2)) < 165){that.y = 150}
                        if((that.y + (img.height/2)) > 165 && (that.y + (img.height/2)) < 175){that.y = 160}
                        if((that.y + (img.height/2)) > 175 && (that.y + (img.height/2)) < 185){that.y = 170}
                        if((that.y + (img.height/2)) > 185 && (that.y + (img.height/2)) < 195){that.y = 180}
                        if((that.y + (img.height/2)) > 195 && (that.y + (img.height/2)) < 205){that.y = 190}
                    });

                }
                //Makes the image 'drag' across the screen.
                if (drag) {
                    that.x = mouseX - startX;
                    that.y = mouseY - startY;
                }
                ctx.drawImage(img, that.x, that.y);
                DrawLines();
            }
        }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

"Bad quality code"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Övning 2</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    *,body{
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        text-align: center;
        background:url('bilder/background.png');
    }
    canvas{
        border: 1px #999999 solid;
        margin-top: 50px;
        box-shadow: 2px 2px 1px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75) inset;
    }

    button{
    white-space:nowrap; 
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;  
    background:#C22E3A;
    border:1px black solid;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:white;
    padding: 6px 9px;
    border-radius:3px;
    margin:5px;
    padding-left:50px;
    padding-right: 50px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    text-shadow: 0px -1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    transition: background-color linear 0.07s;
    }

    button:active{
    top:3px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
    #inputBox{
        display: none;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="900" height="400"></canvas><br />
    <button id="start" onclick="Activate()">Start</button><br />
    <input type="text" id="inputBox">


    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
        var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

        var start = false;

        var helnot = "bilder/helnot.png";
        var helnot2 = new RandomizeNote(helnot);

        var gKlav = new Image();
        gKlav.src = "bilder/g-klav.png";

        var loop = setInterval(function() {
            if(start){
                document.getElementById('start').style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById('inputBox').style.display = "inline";
                helnot2.update();
            }

            Sheet();
        }, 30);

        function Sheet(){
            ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
            ctx.fillRect(200,160,500,1);
            ctx.fillRect(200,180,500,1);
            ctx.fillRect(200,200,500,1);
            ctx.fillRect(200,220,500,1);
            ctx.fillRect(200,240,500,1);
            ctx.drawImage(gKlav, 200, 150);
        }

        function Activate(){
            start = true;
        }

        function RandomizeNote(src){

            var img = new Image();
            img.src = src;

            this.update = function(){
                ctx.drawImage(img, 430, 150);
            }

        }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```